# unit testing not running in vs but run fine in azure CI pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, mstest

I have some unit tests made with MSTest, everything was running fine locally in Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 and tests also ran fine in Azure DevOps CI build. I had to change to a new machine today with a freshly installed VS. The problem is no tests will run locally ever since I started working in this new VS environment (the tests still run fine in the CI build).

Can anyone tell me why this is? Am I missing some packages or so? MSTest framework/adapter etc. is installed locally of course

Locally in VS:

[image: 6 not run]

Azure DevOps CI build:

[image: total tests passed: 6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@craig2020, try to execute this steps:

Clean the solution.

Go to top menu *Test > Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Project > x64*.

And if you're using **git**:

Close the solution and execute *git clean -xfd* on the solution directory.

Open VS and try to execute the tests again.